# Can I 'include' another file in a page xml file

Tags: nativescript

I've got a few pages that are similar - is it possible to include another file including the shared elements.

Comment: Short answer: Yes. Are you using {N} + Angular2?

Comment: No just {N}....

Comment: Put another way...I'm asking whether I can nest a xml snippet in another xml file. I saw a notation like <ns:filename/> but that doesn't work.

Comment: You could review the example here - https://github.com/tsonevn/NSCustomView , where has been shown how to create CustomView using XML and how to include it in another file.

Comment: What you are looking for are custom component there is info about it at `docs.nativescript.org`

Comment: ok i'll look there... I tried the custom view example (thanks). In my code inside the customview I have a Telerik DrawerPage ` <dpg:DrawerPage.sideDrawer>
        <drawer:RadSideDrawer id="sideDrawer">
          <drawer:RadSideDrawer.drawerContent>` When I do a getViewById("sideDrawer") - i get undefined.

Comment: Basically, I've got a SideDrawer definition and I would like to include it in two parent page xml definitions - so that I don't have to copy/paste everytime I make a change. This is {N} only app.

Comment: Definitions is one time thing so why need to change it afterward? and if its inside custom component code do it inside custom component code file

Comment: Because I'm in active dev mode and it changes...also there's another place I'd like to use this if possible. I created the custom-view as defined in NSCustomView (above) - but I get an undefined when I do a page.getViewById("XX") where XX is defined in the custom-view.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can do it.

https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/basics#custom-components

> You can define your own XML namespaces to create custom user interface
>   components. The custom components can be created via XML files or via
>   code-behind JS/TS implementation.